# Find all the paths from the root node to the given node in a general tree

Tags: java, node.js, tree, binary-tree

I want to find all the paths from the root node to the given node in a general tree. Tree is a poly hierarchy tree and may have circles in it. For example I have data like this

```
a b
a c
a z
b e
b d
e f
f e
c g
e g
g h
```

I want to get all the paths from a to h. Result for the above example is two paths of

```
a    a
b    c
e    g
g    h
h
```

I tried Dijkstras algorithm but it only gets me shortest path also it seems overkill. Can any one suggest easier way to find them? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a recursive function that allows no repeated nodes in the history is all that is needed.  Like so:

```
public class FindPath {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Node a = new Node("a");
        Node b = new Node("b");
        Node c = new Node("c");
        Node d = new Node("d");
        Node e = new Node("e");
        Node f = new Node("f");
        Node g = new Node("g");
        Node h = new Node("h");
        Node z = new Node("z");
        a.add(b); a.add(c); a.add(z);
        b.add(e); b.add(d);
        e.add(f); e.add(g);
        f.add(e);
        c.add(g);
        g.add(h);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> viablePaths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>>();
        findPaths(a, "h", new ArrayList<Node>(), viablePaths);
        for (ArrayList<Node> path: viablePaths) {
            print(path);
        }
    }

    public static void findPaths(Node start, String endName, ArrayList<Node> startingPath, ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> viablePaths) {
        startingPath.add(start);
        for (Node next: start.children) {
            ArrayList<Node> extendedPath = (ArrayList<Node>) startingPath.clone();
            if (next.equals(endName)) {
                extendedPath.add(next);
                viablePaths.add(extendedPath);
            } else {
                boolean nodeAlreadyUsed = false;
                for (Node existingNode: startingPath) {
                    if (next.equals(existingNode)) nodeAlreadyUsed = true;
                }
                if (!nodeAlreadyUsed) {
                    findPaths(next, endName, extendedPath, viablePaths);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void print(ArrayList<Node> path) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (Node node: path) sb.append(node + " ");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}

class Node {
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    public Node(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public boolean equals (Node other) {return other.name.equals(name);}
    public boolean equals (String other) {return other.equals(name);}
    public void add(Node child) {children.add(child);}
    public String toString() {return name;}
}
```

This will print:

```
a b e g h 
a c g h
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It working fine for small files. I tried to run it on large file having 3M nodes. Can you suggest any optimization in the algorithm or any existing libraries which can solve quickly. thanks

Comment: @shalini how much memory are you giving the application?  Have you specified the memory arguments?  For example:  java -jar FindPath -Xms10G -Xmx10G

Comment: @shalini the challenge is that at every decision point the full path up to that point needs to be remembered so that it can be inspected for repeats.  For millions of paths, this can add up.  If upping the memory for the app doesn't work, I don't immediately see a solution.

Comment: I ran it with  -Xms40G -Xmx20G, It didnt give any result :(.  But thanks for the comments.